# how to place the select option as the first option on the dropdown?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I added 'Select Gas' as the default value, but the problem is when I sort the @Gases variable, 'Select Gas' goes to the middle of the dropdown. I would like the 'Select Gas' to be the first item even if @Gases got sorted. How can I do this? Thank you

Gases Variable

```
@Gases = ['Carbon Dioxide [CO2]','Ethanol [CH3CH2OH]','Hydrogen [H2]','Hydrogen Sulfide [H2S]', 'Nitrogen Dioxide [NO2]', 'Carbon Monoxide [CO]', 'Ethene [Ethylene C2H6]', 'Other']
```

Search

```
<%= f.select :gas_analyte, @Gases, {include_blank: 'Select Gas', size:15},{class: "gas_search"} %><br>
```

Comment: Where are you sorting `@Gases`? The `include_blank` option should always be the very first item in the dropdown. Testing your code out worked fine for me. Can you show the exact code that's not working for you?

Answer (score 1):

Although your code looks good, if you have an array and you want a particular item to always come first you can use [`Array#prepend`](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/Array/prepend) to get the job done:

```rb
list = [:a, :h, :w, :c, :d, :b, :e]

list.sort.prepend(:z)
=> [:z, :a, :b, :c, :d, :e, :h, :w]
```

So in your case you might have:

```rb
@gases = ['Carbon Dioxide [CO2]','Ethanol [CH3CH2OH]','Hydrogen [H2]','Hydrogen Sulfide [H2S]', 'Nitrogen Dioxide [NO2]', 'Carbon Monoxide [CO]', 'Ethene [Ethylene C2H6]', 'Other']

@gases.sort.prepend('<Select Gas>')
=> ["<Select Gas>", "Carbon Dioxide [CO2]", "Carbon Monoxide [CO]", "Ethanol [CH3CH2OH]", "Ethene [Ethylene C2H6]", "Hydrogen Sulfide [H2S]", "Hydrogen [H2]", "Nitrogen Dioxide [NO2]", "Other"]
```